# Include two versions of jQuery on a page without affecting old plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, jquery-plugins, drupal-theming

Our drupal site runs with jQuery version 1.2.1 which we have not upgraded.

The problem is this:

We need to add a new plugin named jQuery Tokeninput, but it's working only in latest jQuery versions.  We tried adding the latest jQuery version with old version, but it produces weird results.

My question is, how to include the latest jQuery file without affecting the old jQuery plugins?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Method #1: (recommended)**

You could do something like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery_1.7.1.js'></script>   
<script type='text/javascript'>  
 // In case you wonder why we pass the "true" parameter,
 // here is the explanation:
 //   - When you use jQuery.noConflict(), it deletes
 //     the "$" global variable.
 //   - When you use jQuery.noConflict(true), it also
 //     deletes the "jQuery" global variable.
 var $jq = jQuery.noConflict(true);  
</script>  
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery_1.2.1.js'></script>
```

And this way when you want something made with the new version of jquery instead of the `$` use `$jq`.

```
$jq('.selector').on('click', function(){  
    //do something  
});
```

**Method #2: (might break things on your site - not recommended)**

In your `template.php` file:

```
<?php
function {theme_name}_preprocess(&$vars, $hook) {
if (arg(0) != 'admin' && $hook == "page") {
// Get an array of all JavaScripts that have been added
$javascript = drupal_add_js(NULL, NULL, 'header');

// Remove the original jQuery library
unset($javascript['core']['misc/jquery.js']);

// Add in our new jQuery library
// We do it this way to keep the includes in the same order
$core = array(
//Alternative jQuery
drupal_get_path('theme', '{theme_name}').'/js/libs/jquery-1.7.1.min.js' => array(
'cache' => TRUE,
'defer' => FALSE,
)
);

// Merge back into the array of core JavaScripts
$javascript['core'] = array_merge($javascript['core'], $core);

// Rerender the block of JavaScripts
$vars['scripts'] = drupal_get_js(NULL, $javascript);
}
}
```

**Be sure to only do this on the frontend of your site. It can mess up admin toolbars if they are dependent on Drupal's version of jQuery.**

Comment: The second method is good. The first method however, can break your site. There is a reason why the "jQuery Update" module only gets the 1.3.* version on d6.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I updated my answer to recommend the better solution.

Comment: Also, use `jQuery.noConflict( true )`, otherwise the two versions of jQuery will collide :-). `jQuery.noConflict()` just removes the `$` variable, passing the `true` parameter also removes the `jQuery` variable.

Answer (score 3):

The following script...

- is completely **backward compatible** with pre-existing scripts
- should have no side effects (except for obvious side effect of adding an additional JS download)
- allows **any versions of jQuery in any order** -- you can have the "default" be an old version of jQuery and the "additional" be a newer version, or vice versa.

## How to use 2 versions of jQuery on the same page

```html
<!-- IMPORTANT: ORDER is vital. Do not change the order of the following. -->

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    // Save original jQuery version to another variable
    var $Original = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    // Save new jQuery version to another variable
    var $v1_11_0 = jQuery.noConflict(true);

    // Replace the original jquery version on $ and jQuery so pre-existing scripts don't break
    // No need to declare "var" here since the $ and jQuery still exist as "undefined"
    $ = $Original;
    jQuery = $Original;

    // Optional: Here I'm saving new jQuery version as a method of "$" -- it keeps it more organized (in my opinion)
    $.v1_11_0 = $v1_11_0;
</script>
```

## See it in action here:

http://jsfiddle.net/dd94h/

## Here's the entire HTML that you can drop in an html file to test

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQuery within jQuery</title>
    <style media="all" type="text/css">
        h1 span { font-weight: normal; }
    </style>

    <!-- IMPORTANT: ORDER is vital. Do not change the order of the following. -->

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Save original jQuery version to another variable
        var $Original = jQuery.noConflict(true);
    </script>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Save new jQuery version to another variable
        var $v1_11_0 = jQuery.noConflict(true);

        // Replace the original jquery version on $ and jQuery so pre-existing scripts don't break
        // No need to declare "var" here since the $ and jQuery still exist as "undefined"
        $ = $Original;
        jQuery = $Original;

        // Optional: Here I'm saving new jQuery version as a method of "$" -- it keeps it more organized (in my opinion)
        $.v1_11_0 = $v1_11_0;
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Default jQuery: <span id="default-jquery">Loading...</span></h1>
<h1>Additional jQuery: <span id="additional-jquery">Loading...</span></h1>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed id felis quam. Morbi ultrices nisi vel odio vestibulum nec faucibus diam congue. Etiam cursus, turpis id rutrum adipiscing, ligula justo rhoncus ipsum, sed posuere diam orci vel mi. Etiam condimentum tincidunt metus, non dictum ligula hendrerit et. Nulla facilisi. Aenean eleifend volutpat nibh, eu tempor nulla auctor ac. Proin ultrices cursus scelerisque. Curabitur sem sapien, tempus et dictum nec, viverra vel odio. Nulla ullamcorper nisl a dolor laoreet eu eleifend tellus semper. Curabitur vitae sodales nisl. Donec tortor urna, viverra sed luctus in, elementum sit amet turpis.</p>

<script>
    // Continue to use "$" for the original jQuery version
    $( document ).ready(function(){
        $('#default-jquery').text($().jquery);
    });

    // Use $.v1_11_0(...) for the newly-added version
    $.v1_11_0( document ).ready(function(){
        $.v1_11_0('#additional-jquery').text($.v1_11_0().jquery);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know, there is a [jQuery update module](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) which will update jQuery versions for you without you having to code it. Look into it if it's of interest but I don't think that the module keeps the old jQuery version but rather replaces it with the new one.

I might also suggest that you try upgrading the version of jQuery and just using the latest one to see if it does indeed break other functionalities.

Comment: You're right, it replaces it, which is basically not what the OP asked for. jQuery update is great, but only if you don't have a MASSIVE site with loads of old plugins and no room for regression testing (sob).